# Lru Cache очистить данные

Tags: android, кэширование

Всем привет! С помощью `LruCache` кэшировал несколько изображений. Кто знает как теперь эти кэшированные изображения удалить из кэша?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[remove()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html#remove(K))

[evictAll()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html#evictAll())